# How to change $_REQUEST['something'] for $_user['something']?

Tags: request

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["$something"])) {
    $user["$something"] = $_REQUEST["$something"];

}
```

Need to change the variable name for use in class.
Easy way?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out your question. Maybe do you want pick up the value from resquest and put in your Array ?

```
   if (isset($_REQUEST["something"])) {
$user["something"] = $_REQUEST["something"];
```

}